# Error Invalid data type, must be an array or \\ArrayAccess instance

Tags: angularjs, rest, cakephp

When I send a image and text data, have the next problem, this happend when I send data from angular to cakephp 3 with rest service and don't know how solve:

```
Possibly unhandled rejection: {
    "data":{
      "message":"Invalid data type, must be an array or \\ArrayAccess instance.",
      "url":"/documents/add",
      "code":500,
     "file":"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\frontend_dekma\\app\\vendor\\cakephp\\cakephp\\src\\Utility\\Hash.php",
      "line":51
    }, 
    "status":500,
    "config":{
      "method":"POST",
      "transformResponse":[null],
      "jsonpCallbackParam":"callback",
    "headers":{
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers":
      "Accept, Authorization, Cache-Control, Content-Type, X-Requested-With, x-csrf-token",
      "Accept":"application/json",
    "Authorization":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjEsImV4cCI6MTQ5NzYzNzczNX0.im1g6BeHhMAF-MA0jhzYsU15UAH6BS1tByIqbj2acAQ"},
    "url":"/app/documents/add",
    "data":{}
    },
    "statusText":"Internal Server Error"}
```

Now in angular have my service for send this information:

```
.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
            this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
                var formData = new FormData();
                console.log(file);
                // here take the values
                formData.append('photo', file.photo);
                formData.append('descripcion', file.descripcion);
                //show values formData
                for (var key of formData.entries()) {
                    console.log(key[0] + ', ' + key[1]);
                }
                //post url uploadUrl = '/app/documents/add'
                $http.post(uploadUrl, formData, {
                    transformRequest: angular.identity,
                    headers: {
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Accept, Authorization, Cache-Control, Content-Type, X-Requested-With, x-csrf-token',
                        'Content-Type': undefined
                    }
                })
                .then(function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                });
            }
        }])
```

This is the controller on my backend:

```
   public function add()
    {
        $document = $this->Documents->newEntity();
        $data = ['result' => 'null', 'id' => 'null'];
        if ($this->request->is('post'))
        {
            $document = $this->Documents->patchEntity($document, $this->request->getData());
            if ($this->Documents->save($document))
            {
                $data = ['result' => 'success', 'id' => $document->id];
            } else {
                $data = ['result' => 'error'];
            }
        }
        $this->set(compact('data'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['data']);
    }
```

**GOOD I DID SOMETHING DIFFERENT BUT HELP ME TO DETECT WHERE IS THE PROBLEM**

first I try to use [cakephp-upload](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/cakephp-upload). But initially with the example of the blog did not understand well how it worked so in the beginning I ran into this error I did not understand either. Now I treat in a different way, everything works until I tried to store the data in the database is here when the error occurs, Actually continued with the same error at the beginning of the post but now I know where is the problem:

After hours of many test I comment this part and work fine, but obviously not store nothing on the DataBase. With a different code. now work, but need that store the data on the database, and understand the error.

```
public function add()
{
    $document = $this->Documents->newEntity();
    $data = ['result' => $this->request->getData(), 'id' => 'null'];
    $file = $this->request->getData('photo');
    $file['name'] =  time() . '-' . str_replace(' ', '_', $file['name']); // timestamp files to prevent clobber
    if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], WWW_ROOT . 'files/' . $file['name']))
    {
        //When comment this part dont have error 
        //but can't save in the data base my information
        //
        /* 
        $document->photo = $file['name'];
        $document->descripcion = $this->request->getData('descripcion');
        $document = $this->Documents->patchEntity($document, $this->request->getData());
        if ($this->Documents->save($document)) {
            $data = ['result' => 'success', 'id' => $document->id];
        }
        */

    }
    $this->set(compact('data'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['data']);
}
```

Comment: The content type for uploading file should be multipart/form-data. Have you tried this?

Comment: yes but have other error 'Error: $http:baddata
Bad JSON Data
Data must be a valid JSON object. Received: '

Comment: I'm not familiar with Angular. I'd suggest that you try to isolate the problem further, ie figure whether it's the Angular side, or the CakePHP side (or maybe even both). Start with checking your browsers network console and inspecting whether the request looks like expected/required (headers and data).

Comment: I am sure that the problem is of cakephp now I made many tests I will raise a new question with the advanced.

Comment: Please don't... instead update this question with more information, your new question completely lacks the angular part, ie the very bit that would help to understand what data you're actually trying to send. Try to imagine the people reading this, they can't look over your shoulder, they have no clue what's going on, hence they need enough information (like the exact data being sent and retrieved, in case of an error the related stacktrace, etc) in order to be able to comprehend the problem.

Comment: It's okay, I understand, I'm starting to do

Answer (score 0):

The exception is occuring at line ~80:
/home/user/myapp/vendor/josegonzalez/cakephp-upload/src/Model/Behavior/UploadBehavior.php

```
public function beforeSave(Event $event, Entity $entity, ArrayObject $options)
{
    foreach ($this->config() as $field => $settings) {
        if (Hash::get((array)$entity->get($field), 'error') !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            HERE ---> if (Hash::get($settings, 'restoreValueOnFailure', true)) {
```

The tutorial of the blog is for earlier version if cake or not ok.
Check this doc: http://cakephp-upload.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html

In your DocumentsTable.php you should have something like this:

```
$this->addBehavior('Josegonzalez/Upload.Upload', [
    'path' => [],
]);
```

The 'path' should not be a value, but a key to an array: 'path' => [],

Comment: I just found more detail on that: https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/cakephp-upload/issues/428